# User Authentication using flask_login with angular

Tags: angular, flask, flask-login

I am building an app using flask and angular. I used flask_login for user authentication which checks `@login_rquired` before accessing an API. The backend works fine when used in postman, even user authentication. But when I use angular, the `error 401 user not authenticated` is shown. I have set correct cors-headers and sending a param `withCredentials: true` with every request.

```
CORS(frontend, resources={
     r"/*": {"origins": "http://localhost:4200", "supports_credentials": True}})
```

The login works but user authentication does not when using angular. I want to know whether and what am I missing.